# remove admin user vesta panel Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, vps

So I recently uninstalled Vesta Panel in my Ubuntu VPS, and it said "You might also consider to delete admin user account and its cron jobs."

Now that I want to reinstall Vesta is says

"Error: User admin already exists

Please remove admin user account before proceeding"

How would I got about removing the admin user account after I've already uninstalled Vesta?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sudo userdel [useraccount]`

Followed by

`sudo rm -rf /home/useraccount`

Followed by

`vi /etc/crontab` and inspecting /etc/crond.d for cron jobs are left behind that need to be removed.

Comment: @mertyildiran it sounds like you should make your own answer to this.  There's way too much changed for this to be an edit.